# Adding date ticks to ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add ticks to my x-axis in this graph to show all the months of the year:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(df_test, aes(time, reading))
p + geom_point(alpha = 1/4) + geom_smooth()
```

I have tried to use [scale_x_date](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html) but have come across the following error:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Here's the data frame I'm using:

```
 hour   reading   date                time
 1      53        1/1/15 2015-01-01 01:00:00
 2      55        1/1/15 2015-01-01 02:00:00
 3      56        1/1/15 2015-01-01 03:00:00
```

The class of my time variable:

> class(df_test$time)
>   "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

Comment: Well, what is the class of `df_test$time`??

Comment: Edited to show the data frame being used. I believe it is of class datetime, but not entirely sure how to check.

Comment: `class(df_test$time)`. You should provide your data, or a representative sample (enough to demonstrate the problem), using `dput(df_test)`.

Comment: I've outputted dput(df_test) but how would be the best practice to share this data?

Comment: Depends on how much there is. You could `dput(head(df_test, 100))` (the first 100 rows) if that is enough to demonstrate the problem. Or you could upload the dataset somewhere and post a link, but that might be overkill in this case. Anyway, does my answer solve your problem? POSIXct whould not be a problem with `scale_x_date(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the answers of both @PaulHiemstra and @jihoward, I've managed to figure out an answer.

First using the dplyr library to rework the data:

```
library(dplyr)
df_test1 = df_test %>% mutate(time = as.Date(time))
```

Then using scale_x_dates:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(df_test1, aes(time, reading))
p + geom_point(alpha = 1/4)+
  scale_x_date(breaks="month", labels=date_format("%b"))
```

Gives the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `scale_x_date(breaks="month", labels=date_format("%b%))`. Here's an example.

```
library(quantmod)
sp500 <- getSymbols("SP500", src="FRED", auto.assign=FALSE)
sp500 <- sp500["2015-01-01::"]
sp500 <- data.frame(time=as.POSIXct(index(sp500), origin="1970-01-01"),sp500)
class(sp500$time)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)    # for date_format(...)
ggplot(sp500, aes(x=as.Date(time), y=SP500))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(breaks="month", labels=date_format("%b"))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Comment: @ttct so probably the `time` variable is not a date object, but probably a character.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra He posted `class(df_test$time)` in his question.

Comment: I've shared the data frame here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-utsAVxMcQ5ckNxVjRZYWFKT0k

Comment: Can you make it public? Google wants me to log in.

Comment: Casting the `POSIXlt/POSIXct' object to `date` should do the trick, see `as.date`. @jlhoward I had not seen the edit.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a scale specific for `Date` on a `POSIXct` object. The solution is to cast the `POSIXct` object to a `date` using `as.date`:

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2015-09-16 09:52:42 CEST"
> as.Date(Sys.time())
[1] "2015-09-16"
```

To do this on your `data.frame`, I recommend using the `dplyr` package:

```
df_test = df_test %>% mutate(time = as.Date(time))
```

Comment: After installing the dplyr package, I'm getting the following error: Error: could not find function "as.date". Would you have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Fixed it, just had to capitalize the 'd' in as.date(time)

Comment: @tctt also fixed the typo in my answer, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Since the most recent answers (2015) `date_format()` is deprecated (I believe). Replace it with `label_date()` or `scales::label_date()`. It may not be loaded in your namespace but should come with ggplot so `scales::` might be necessary.

Here's a copy and paste of the @timothyylim accepted answer with the change.

```
library(dplyr)
df_test1 = df_test %>% mutate(time = as.Date(time))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(df_test1, aes(time, reading))
p + geom_point(alpha = 1/4)+
  scale_x_date(breaks="month", labels = scales::label_date("%b"))
```

Comment: Or for example, you can you use `scale_x_date(date_breaks="2 months", date_labels = "%b")`.